# Редактирование меток - нужен совет

Tags: обсуждение, метки, вопросы

Это коротенький вопрос по поводу редактирования меток. Я только начал просматривать вопросы пользователей, и начинаю замечать, что многие не всегда правильно подбирают метки для своих вопросов. Например, очевидно что [android-studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) и [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) - это две совершенно разные метки. Так как я занимаюсь [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) разработкой, то соответственно подписан на вопросы по мобильной разработке. Довольно часто я вижу, что некоторые пользователи вместе с меткой [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) используют метку [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). С одной стороны как-бы все правильно, ведь на данный момент этот язык программирования используется для написания приложений и использование этой метки не смертельно. Но с другой стороны мне кажется что не нужно использовать эту метку для вопросов по мобильной разработке, так как большинство вопросов касается работы не с самим языком программирования, а с прописанными методами и библиотеками.

У меня дилемма, нужно ли убирать эту метку, или оставлять так как есть?

Comment: Злоупотреблять не стоит

Comment: Я просто уточняю,потому что только начал править чужие вопросы,   и не хочется обижать новых пользователей))

Comment: Да, обидеть человека, неудачно "исправив" его сообщение, легко. На добавленную метку скорее всего никто не отреагирует. А на замененную/удаленную?  Кроме того, правки вытаскивают вопрос снова на главную страницу, что раздражает. Поэтому и не стоит плотно ими заниматься.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Человек может быть подписан на метку [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) и не быть специалистом по [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). Но по Android очень много именно программистских вопросов. Если там не будет метки [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), то подписавшиеся только на [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) могут пропустить вопрос.

Так что, в случае [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) метка [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) обычно вполне уместна.

Метка [android-studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) должна использоваться для вопросов, касающихся этой IDE, а не только потому что человек использует эту среду разработки. Зачастую эту метку используют не к месту.